# sql insert using charindex

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have this INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempSequences]
(Title, Sequence, FileTrackingTag)
SELECT Title, Sequence, FileTrackingTag
FROM   [dbo].[MasterSequence]
WHERE  charindex(',' + FileTrackingTag + ',', ',' + @filetag + ',') > 0;
```

Where FileTrackingTag is the one associated with said title and sequence.  However I am giving it a string of these tags

i.e.

```
 'tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4'
```

How can I put the correct tag in there?  Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with your current statement?  You might put some sample data up to illuminate the issue.

Comment: In MaserSequence, we can have for TItle, Sequence, FileTrackingTag

    mytitle1, myseq1, tag1
    mytitle2, myseq2, tag2
    mytitle3, myseq3, tag3

and I want to input in for @filetag 'tag1,tag2'

Comment: The example would return (or insert) 2 rows: `mytitle1` and `mytitle2`, correct?

Comment: In my dev environment, that is exactly what your existing query does.  are you encountering an error?  What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to put only the one supplied tag via parameter instead of the whole sequence then:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempSequences] 
(Title, Sequence, FileTrackingTag) 
SELECT Title, Sequence, @filetag  
FROM   [dbo].[MasterSequence] 
WHERE  charindex(',' + FileTrackingTag + ',', ',' + @filetag + ',') > 0;
```

Comment: that then inserts 'tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4'
rather than 'tag1' or 'tag2'

Comment: I misunderstood. What is the value of FileTrackingTag then? Are you looking for it to insert of 'union' of overlapping values? Give me a scenario of both @filetag and FileTrackingTag values and say what you expect the result value to be

Comment: I am inputting in 'tag1,tag2' and I want it output in @filetag either tag1 or tag2

Comment: If FileTrackingTag is tag1 or tag2 then like @Tim says it should produce the value you are looking for. If FileTrackingTag is a comma delimited list then you've got an issue because it could technically be more than one value.